# Is there a way to make a checkstyle the default Checkstyle for all Java projects?

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I find it highly tedious that Checkstyles in IntelliJ are per project. There is always someone (including myself) who forgets to import them when a new IntelliJ project is created, and gets a bunch of styling errors back during QA.

Comment: From the Welcome Screen, Configure | Project Defaults | Settings, Other Settings | Checkstyle?

Comment: Thanks to your comment my brain started looking for a Default setting, while having a project open. It was located in File | Other Settings | Default Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting I was looking for could be found under File | Other Settings | Default Settings, while having a Java project open in IntelliJ.

I assume this is the same settings as CrazyCoder references in his comment, just a different way of reaching it.

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Adding a checkstyle configuration in default doesn't make it appear in concrete project. :( Restarting Intellij etc., nothing. Still visible in default settings, but not accessable in project settings. Version: IDEA 2017.2, Build #IC-172.3317.76, built on July 15, 2017

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting Checkstyle in **IDE Settings**. These settings are *common for all projects and refer to the project-independent aspects*.

Read this article for more info: [Project and IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/project-and-ide-settings.html).

Comment: I managed to find the setting I was looking for. While having an arbitrery Java project open it can be found under: File | Other Settings | Default Settings.